# Monotouch template Open GL application draw call generates fault?

Tags: opengl-es, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, ios4

I installed latest ios sdk 4.3, latest Monotouch and MonoDevelop updates. Create template open GL application (the rotating colourful sq) called it TestBug and on call draw I get the application output below. Application continues to run but this is the first time I see the application ouput when stepping over the call GL.DrawArrays in EagleView.cs. Is anyone else seeing this or can clue me to what I might have done wrong? Apologies for the spew.

Native stacktrace:

```
    0   TestBug                             0x000b7b4d mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 343
    1   TestBug                             0x0000e12f mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 226
    2   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9755d45b _sigtramp + 43
    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
    4   libLLVMContainer.dylib              0x0229ea48 _ZN4llvm21PrettyStackTraceEntryC2Ev + 84
    5   libLLVMContainer.dylib              0x02215f9e _ZN4llvm13FPPassManager13runOnFunctionERNS_8FunctionE + 232
    6   libLLVMContainer.dylib              0x02217167 _ZN4llvm23FunctionPassManagerImpl3runERNS_8FunctionE + 197
    7   libLLVMContainer.dylib              0x0221726b _ZN4llvm19FunctionPassManager3runERNS_8FunctionE + 83
    8   libCoreVMClient.dylib               0x01c3ca79 cvmsCompBuildMonolithicFunction + 1376
    9   libCoreVMClient.dylib               0x01c40991 cvmsServerBuildMonolithicFunction + 235
    10  libCoreVMClient.dylib               0x01c3e589 CVMSBuildMonolithicFunction + 92
    11  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib          0x01c360d1 _Z29cvm_deferred_build_monolithicPv + 120
    12  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib          0x01c35918 cvmDoWork + 111
    13  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x975247fd _pthread_start + 345
    14  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x97524682 thread_start + 34

Debug info from gdb:

warning: Could not find object file "/var/folders/Vv/VvqxJ24WGcqs6wHSaxcLWE+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp60099686.tmp/main.o" - no debug information available for "/var/folders/Vv/VvqxJ24WGcqs6wHSaxcLWE+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp60099686.tmp/main.m".

Attaching to process 5300.
Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
Reading symbols for shared libraries ......................................................................... done
0x974f709a in mach_msg_trap ()
  8                         0x975023fe in read$UNIX2003 ()
  7 "WebThread"             0x974f709a in mach_msg_trap ()
  6                         0x97525046 in __semwait_signal ()
  5                         0x974f70d6 in semaphore_wait_trap ()
  4                         0x974f709a in mach_msg_trap ()
  3                         0x9751d922 in kevent ()
  2                         0x9751c9b2 in __workq_kernreturn ()
* 1 "com.apple.main-thread" 0x974f709a in mach_msg_trap ()

Thread 8 (process 5300):
#0  0x975023fe in read$UNIX2003 ()
#1  0x000b7cfd in mono_handle_native_sigsegv (signal=11, ctx=0xb0454bb0) at ../../../../mono/mini/mini-exceptions.c:1826
#2  0x0000e12f in mono_sigsegv_signal_handler (_dummy=10, info=0xb0454b70, context=0xb0454bb0) at ../../../../mono/mini/mini.c:4810
#3  <signal handler called>
#4  0x022bd630 in llvm::sys::AddSignalHandler ()
#5  0x0229ea48 in llvm::PrettyStackTraceEntry::PrettyStackTraceEntry ()
#6  0x02215f9e in llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction ()
#7  0x02217167 in llvm::FunctionPassManagerImpl::run ()
#8  0x0221726b in llvm::FunctionPassManager::run ()
#9  0x01c3ca79 in cvmsCompBuildMonolithicFunction ()
#10 0x01c40991 in cvmsServerBuildMonolithicFunction ()
#11 0x01c3e589 in CVMSBuildMonolithicFunction ()
#12 0x01c360d1 in cvm_deferred_build_monolithic ()
#13 0x01c35918 in cvmDoWork ()
#14 0x975247fd in _pthread_start ()
#15 0x97524682 in thread_start ()

Thread 7 (process 5300):
#0  0x974f709a in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x974f7807 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x0144cd86 in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x013a9e74 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x013a9840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x013a9761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x03924913 in RunWebThread ()
#7  0x975247fd in _pthread_start ()
#8  0x97524682 in thread_start ()

Thread 6 (process 5300):
#0  0x97525046 in __semwait_signal ()
#1  0x97550ec5 in nanosleep$UNIX2003 ()
#2  0x97550e03 in usleep$UNIX2003 ()
#3  0x002592b8 in monotouch_pump_gc (context=0x0) at monotouch-glue.m:326
#4  0x975247fd in _pthread_start ()
#5  0x97524682 in thread_start ()

Thread 5 (process 5300):
#0  0x974f70d6 in semaphore_wait_trap ()
#1  0x001508e8 in finalizer_thread (unused=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/gc.c:1026
#2  0x001f1eb8 in start_wrapper (data=0x4f228c0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/threads.c:661
#3  0x0022e94a in thread_start_routine (args=0x505ba34) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/wthreads.c:286
#4  0x00256d79 in GC_start_routine (arg=0x5fc9f60) at ../../../libgc/pthread_support.c:1390
#5  0x975247fd in _pthread_start ()
#6  0x97524682 in thread_start ()

Thread 4 (process 5300):
#0  0x974f709a in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x974f7807 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x00114577 in mach_exception_thread (arg=0x0) at ../../../../mono/mini/mini-darwin.c:138
#3  0x975247fd in _pthread_start ()
#4  0x97524682 in thread_start ()

Thread 3 (process 5300):
#0  0x9751d922 in kevent ()
#1  0x01b85f36 in _dispatch_mgr_invoke ()
#2  0x01b86333 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#3  0x01b86593 in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#4  0x9751cd21 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#5  0x9751cb66 in start_wqthread ()

Thread 2 (process 5300):
#0  0x9751c9b2 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x9751cf48 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#2  0x9751cb66 in start_wqthread ()

Thread 1 (process 5300):
#0  0x974f709a in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x974f7807 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x0144cd86 in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x013a9e74 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x013a9840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x013a9761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x025fd1c4 in GSEventRunModal ()
#7  0x025fd289 in GSEventRun ()
#8  0x00886c93 in UIApplicationMain ()
#9  0x07854681 in ?? ()
#10 0x078545ba in ?? ()
#11 0x0785449d in ?? ()
#12 0x078543d9 in ?? ()
#13 0x07854434 in ?? ()
#14 0x0000df4a in mono_jit_runtime_invoke (method=0x50dde74, obj=0x0, params=0xbfffed8c, exc=0x0) at ../../../../mono/mini/mini.c:4733
#15 0x001baf2b in mono_runtime_invoke (method=0x50dde74, obj=0x0, params=0xbfffed8c, exc=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/object.c:2615
#16 0x001bcb5f in mono_runtime_exec_main (method=0x50dde74, args=0x782d170, exc=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/object.c:3581
#17 0x001bc4a9 in mono_runtime_run_main (method=0x50dde74, argc=0, argv=0xbfffeec4, exc=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/object.c:3355
#18 0x00092d14 in mono_jit_exec (domain=0x5941e58, assembly=0x4f66670, argc=1, argv=0xbfffeec0) at ../../../../mono/mini/driver.c:1094
#19 0x0000349a in main ()

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Comment: This was a good question. IDK who or why someone gave you a mark down. So im giving you a mark up. I was running across the same thing as well.

Answer (score 2):

This was a simulator only bug in MonoTouch which is fixed in an upcoming release.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same behavior with a totally fresh machine install. The GL sample app continues to run fine after this batch of debug spew, but my real app, which uses threads, fails to finish loading in an iPhone Simulator Debug build (regardless of whether I'm actually in the debugger when I run it or not).

My app creates a thread that loads stuff in the background while the frame loop runs, and the thread appears to be stopped inside a UIFont call.

The app still runs with a release build, and this did not happen with the previous iOS SDK / MonoTouch combo.

Here's what I did with a completely fresh hard drive to arrive at this problem:

1. Install Snow Leopard.
2. Installed Xcode 4.0.1 and iOS SDK 4.3.
3. Installed Mono 2.6.7 and 2.10.1
4. Installed MonoDevelop, ran it, and upgraded to latest version (2.4.2)
5. Installed MonoTouch (3.2.6)
6. Created default iPhone project with spinning cube
7. Run on iPhone simulator and I get the same problem genpfault mentions.